# Anaconda - arrow keys not work well in python shell

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Anaconda3 on manjaro (with i3wm and Urxvt). When I go into python interpreter, it is OK to type python script and execute. But when key arrows are pressed to call up history, everything messed up. Here is a screenshot shows the situation after I pressed my up keys several times.[image]And another problem is when backspace is pressed there will be one more space appear but not delete characters before.

I have tried to find some post that saying escape chars appears in Anaconda python and the solution seems to be install `ncurses` or `readline`. When I tried to install them, I found both of them are already in place. Any idea to help with my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to put a compiled terminfo entry in anaconda's temrinfo directory. The entry for urxvt needs to be placed in `$_CONDA_ROOT/share/terminfo/r/`. I ran the following copy and verified it works now:

`cp /usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-unicode-256color ~/anaconda/share/terminfo/r/`

If you have multiple environments you will have to do it for them as well:

`cp /usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-unicode-256color ~/anaconda/envs/data_science/share/terminfo/r/`

Comment: thanks! If using miniconda, it's almost the same, ~/.conda/envs/<ENV>/share/terminfo/r/

Comment: may be wise to copy the whole terminfo dir

Comment: Attempted to perform steps as suggested in answer. terminfo was not within ~/anaconda3/share. I copied the entire terminfo directory, and that did not fix it. I also have nothing in the envs