# Anaconda breaks python interpreter backspace and up-arrow

Tags: python, anaconda

After installing anaconda according to [their insturictions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) on arch, conda seems to work. It managed to install matlotlib. But it breaks python interpreter in a strange way.

- When I type something and then press backspace, one space is inserted. If backspace is pressed again, nothing happens. If I type some more, backspace inserts 1 space again.
- Pressing the up arrow appends the commands from history to what is written in the prompt, not replaces it.

I tried copying contents of my terminfo as desribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183901/anaconda-arrow-keys-not-work-well-in-python-shell). I do not have `rxvt-unicode-256color` in this directory. I do have `rxvt-256color` and other files, but copying them into the anaconda directory did not help.

If I disable anaconda, the issue goes away.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but did you restart your terminal?

Comment: what system do you use? Do you have to use `rxvt`? Maybe you could check it with differnt terminal. Maybe it is problem with terminal, not python.

Comment: I did restart my terminal.

Comment: I use gonome-terimal, but it is the same case with konsole.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by installing [iPython](https://pypi.org/project/ipython/) interactive shell and using that instead of the default python interpreter.

Comment: I had a similar but not identical problem and this worked for me. My command history was broken in that pushing `up` had the same effect as typing `^[[A`. Also, on AWS but not on my own system, a lot of weird garbage characters would appear when I pasted into the Python interpreter.